# MYSQL in PHPMYADMIN - create table relationship from one table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relationship, create-table

I want to create a table relationship with MYSQL PHPMYADMIN.

[image]

I have this Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE students(code_students int(8)not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
name_students varchar(25),
age_students int(3),
degree_program varchar(25),
code_advisor int(8)not null,
primary key(code_students, code_advisor)
);
```

and i want to make a create table named advise relationship between code_students, code_advisor.

Ok this is my tryout.

```
CREATE TABLE advise (
code_students int(8),
code_advisor int(8),
primary key(code_students, code_advisor),
foreign key(code_students)references students(code_students),
foreign key(code_advisor)references students(code_advisor)
);
```

Comment: create second table and share first table id in second table

Comment: do you get an error from this?

Comment: I want to make a table relation something like (students advise students) "students is my parent table" in which relation code_students and code_advisor will be the foreign keys. I hope i cleared it out.

Comment: @hermann yes i am getting this: #1005 - Can't create table 'university.advise' (errno: 150) ... the same error i was getting in the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

[mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) says :

`A FOREIGN KEY constraint that references a non-UNIQUE key is not standard SQL. It is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL`
Try adding the UNIQUE keyword to your first table:

```
CREATE TABLE students(
   code_students int(8)not null unique AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name_students varchar(25),
   age_students int(3),
   degree_program varchar(25),
   code_advisor int(8)not null unique,
   primary key(code_students, code_advisor)
);
```

Check out this sqlFiddle and see how it works, then try removing the UNIQUE keywords and see that you get the same error that you mentioned. ( Hit the `Build Schema` button )

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46b69

Comment: No, it didn't. Shoudn't i provide the primary keys too?

Comment: when i dont have the primary key set it shows me the error #1005 - Can't create table 'university.advise' (errno: 150) ... and when i do set them it shows me a syntax error on the foreign key('s) P.S. this is the only relation that doesn't work.

Comment: make sure you are not missing any commas

Comment: I have added a picture of my E.R. in which shows the relationship.

Comment: i've tried it! well it didn't work. but its okay thank you for your time you don't have to waste anymore of your time on this. Thank you very much for helping me! :)

Comment: @StanleyDecoWood check once again please =)

Comment: and if you remove the unique keyword the schema cannot be built.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19993/discussion-between-hermann-and-stanley-decowood)